# Where do you store UPC codes for products?

Tags: barcode, aspdotnetstorefront

I am working on an install of AspDotNetStoreFront (version 9.3.1.0).  Currently, the company stores their own SKU's from their business system in the provided SKU field.  They often use Manufacturer Part Number to store their vendors part number.

Example:
[image]

The above example is a variant of a product where we would like to store UPC information.

I searched the [AspDotNetStoreFront manuals](http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/) and could not find a recommended strategy for storing UPC codes.  Its easy enough to add a field to the database and bulk import the data, however, an admin needs to be able to maintain them from within the stores user interface.

Is there a way to add a UPC field without modifying core ASPDNSF code and still allow users to maintain it from within the UI?  Or do I have to use the SKU or MPN fields?

**Update**

I do see that there are 5 fields for "ExtensionData" that I could possibly use, but I don't see those fields as editable for Variants in the UI the way ExtensionData is for the Products themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have had customers who didn't use sku for their UPC code. In the event that you need to modify the table by adding another column, you can modify the admin to show this.

You should be ab able to edit entityEditProducts.aspx and entityEditProducts.aspx.cs to edit this in the admin area. You will just need to modify the sql scripts and the view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's important enough for you to upgrade over, but version 9.4 added fields for UPC.  From the 9.4 release notes (http://partners.vortx.com/t-summer2013releasenotes.aspx):

"Added new GTIN field to the product variant information for unique product identification. This new field holds up to 14 characters and can be used for EAN, UPC, ISBN, etc. This new field is included in WSI, Excel & XML Imports, and supported by DotFeed."

The GTIN field works for both variant and size/color.

Comment: Thanks @lindsayweb, we did just upgrade our dev site to 9.4. If it checks out there I will mark this answered.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the 5 extension field given by default in the product table to store UPC code. By default it has also UI in edit product under Extension Data tab.[image]

Comment: Thanks @Avinash Ranjan, but I already Updated my question with why ExtensionData will not work (because of variants)

Comment: if in edit variant 'Manufacturer Part #' is not in use for any product, then you can use it for UPC code , if it makes sense. Other wise you have to add UI in Edit Variant for extension data